# How to generate a sequence of integers with predefined *uniqueness*?

Tags: c++, algorithm

For some testing I need to generate a potentially long **non-random** sequence of integers with predefined *uniqueness*. I define the uniqueness as a floating number, equal to the "number of *unique* numbers in the sequence" divided by the "total sequence length". This number should be in the `(0, 1]` half-open interval.

I might need these sequences with different length, which is unknown in advance - so I need an algorithm to generate such a sequence, for which its *any* prefix sequence has uniqueness, closed to the predefined one. For example, the sequence `1,2,...,m,1,2,...,n` with uniqueness `max(m,n)/(m+n)` is not good for me.

The problem looks simple, because the algorithm should generate just a single sequence - but the function `next()` which I wrote (see below) looks unexpectedly complex, and it also uses the core memory a lot:

```
typedef std::set<uint64_t> USet;
typedef std::map<unsigned, USet> CMap;

const double uniq = 0.25;    // --- the predefined uniqueness 
uint64_t totalSize = 0;      // --- current sequence length
uint64_t uniqSize = 0;       // --- current number of unique integers
uint64_t last = 0;           // --- last added integer
CMap m;                      // --- all numbers, grouped by their cardinality  

uint64_t next()
{
  if (totalSize > 0)
  {
    const double uniqCurrent = static_cast<double>(uniqSize) / totalSize;
    if (uniqCurrent <= uniq)
    {
      // ------ increase uniqueness by adding a new number to the sequence 
      const uint64_t k = ++last;
      m[1].insert(k);
      ++totalSize;
      ++uniqSize;
      return k;
    }
    else
    {
      // ------ decrease uniqueness by repeating an already used number
      CMap::iterator mIt = m.begin();
      while (true)
      {
        assert(mIt != m.cend());
        if (mIt->second.size() > 0) break;
        ++mIt;
      }
      USet& s = mIt->second;
      const USet::iterator sIt = s.cbegin();
      const uint64_t k = *sIt;
      m[mIt->first + 1].insert(k);
      s.erase(sIt);
      ++totalSize;
      return k;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    m[1].insert(0);
    ++totalSize;
    ++uniqSize;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to do that simpler?

Comment: By saying the length is unknown in advance, do you mean that you need to be able to generate fixed sequences of arbitrary length, or that you need to be able to increase the length of a sequence on demand?  These are very different requirements because the latter requires maintaining a stateful object of some kind, while the former can be done using a pure function.

Comment: @ChrisHayden - honestly, I don't see any difference. This function should generate the sequence with *any* length and *any* uniqueness I want. I don't see how to do that without state now, and this state in my function (above) takes a lot of memory, which might prevent it to generate really long sequences - that's also my concern

Comment: Generating a fixed-length sequence with dynamic properties can be accomplished with something like `std::vector<int> generate(<properties>)`, i.e. the sequence is immutable once it's been generated.  That is different from having to be able to dynamically add new elements to an existing sequence.  If I'm not explaining this clearly maybe someone else can do a better job?

Comment: @ChrisHayden - I don't get it... If I need a sequence with many billions of numbers, the function will give me a vector with this length, right? Why is it better than getting numbers one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say anything about trying to get each number to have the same cardinality. The code below does that approximately, but there are some cases where it chooses a number "out of turn" (mostly early in the sequence). Hope the simplicity and the constant space usage makes up for that.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

class Generator {
 public:
  explicit Generator(double uniqueness)
      : uniqueness_(uniqueness), count_(0), unique_count_(0),
        previous_non_unique_(0) {
    assert(uniqueness_ > 0.0);
  }

  int Next() {
    ++count_;
    if (static_cast<double>(unique_count_) / static_cast<double>(count_) <
        uniqueness_) {
      ++unique_count_;
      previous_non_unique_ = 1;
      return unique_count_;
    } else {
      --previous_non_unique_;
      if (previous_non_unique_ <= 0) {
        previous_non_unique_ = unique_count_;
      }
      return previous_non_unique_;
    }
  }

 private:
  const double uniqueness_;
  int count_;
  int unique_count_;
  int previous_non_unique_;
};

int main(void) {
  Generator generator(0.25);
  while (true) {
    std::printf("%d\n", generator.Next());
  }
}
```